# Pulseaudio Sample Rates too Different (A2DP)

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, pulseaudio

#### Issue:

I am running Raspbian (from February 2017). I have setup the Raspberry Pi to run its bluetooth as A2DP and am streaming audio to it via Amazon Echo Dot (Pandora). It runs great for a good 30 minutes then the audio playback just stops. When I go to check the `/var/log/syslogs` I find the following:

#### Errors:

```
Mar 24 22:12:34 raspberrypi pulseaudio[615]: [pulseaudio] module-loopback.c: Sample rates too different, not adjusting (44100 vs. 85062).
...
...
...
Mar 24 22:19:34 raspberrypi pulseaudio[615]: [pulseaudio] module-loopback.c: Sample rates too different, not adjusting (44100 vs. 462646).
```

#### Things I have tried:

I have changed the resample-method from default to trivial and the problem still persists.

I have tried searching online and can't seem to find any similar issues, at least none with any information in what is causing it and none with anything close to resembling a solution.

#### My Conclusion:

To me it looks as though the sample rate from the Echo Dot seems to continue to grow, and pulseaudio can handle it up until the new rate hits the (base rate * x), in which it becomes "too different" and won't adjust to the new rate.

#### Questions:

What can be done? Is there something I can disable that will allow for playback? Is there anyway to reset the incoming rate to a more manageable number once it gets too high?

#### Band-aid Fixes:

I can manually disconnect the Amazon Echo Dot, and reconnect the dot and audio playback will begin again and play normally for another 20-30 minutes until the issue begins again.

#### Update:

I have tried setting the resampling rate again to trivial this time I receive the following error:

```
Mar 25 02:11:45 raspberrypi pulseaudio[595]: [bluetooth] module-bluez5-device.c: SBC decoding error (-2)
```

I am suspecting this is "progress", but what can be about this specific error?

Comment: I'ld suspect that after some time the information in the data stream gets erraneous, and some data are interpreted as "sample rate". Especially 462646 is way too high for sample rates...

Comment: So Is there any work around? And would this possibly be an issue with the dot or with pulse? @ridgy Edit: my assumption would be this is a pulseaudio thing as when reconnecting fixes the issue.